# How to create a chrome extension using multiple css and js files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I would like to adapt my HTML/JS/CSS app to function as a Chrome Extension. I have multiple js files (including two frameworks) and multiple css files. I am unsure how to organize the manifest.json file. In the current format the extension works by generating a new HTML page when the icon is clicked in the browser but the css and js don't function. The extension should pop-up a new HTML page when the extension icon is clicked. Here is my code:

```
{
    "name": "Testing",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Testing Data",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "Test_Ext_Chrome.html"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
    "icon.png",
    "Test_Ext_Chrome.js",
    "jquery-1.11.3.min.js",
    "intro.js",
    "Test_Ext_Chrome.css",
    "introjs.css"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my own extension I only declared the html in the manifest, and the html is reading js and css files just fine.

```
"browser_action" : {
    "default_icon" : "icon.png",
    "default_popup" : "popup.html"
},
```

As for the background Javascript files, I used

```
"background" : {
    "scripts" : ["common.js","background.js"],
    "persistent" : false
},
```

[Web accessible resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) are not to be used by the extension, but by the web pages. "These resources would then be available in a webpage via the URL chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH]"